# How to run a script in Sudo and automatically fill in my password

Tags: ubuntu, windows, for

I have Bash for windows (linux subsystem) and I'm in the process of creating some powershell scripts (just for fun) for apps I run on Linux so I can just launch them from my desktop.

It is all virtualized and offline so I'm really not looking for a lecture in security as I already know the ins and outs of that, just looking to get this working as a fun learning experience ;)

This is what I kind of came up with but there are 2 problems:

1: My script wont continue after the first line (so powershell will drop into bash but not execute the subsequent commands).

2: I need to fill in my root password and I just want it to either skip that or just fill it in for me as some apps need root access.

```
bash (powershell command to drop into the bash shell)
export DISPLAY=:0 (necessary for gui apps)
sudo (app name)
(app asks for password)
Password
```

So if I run these commands one by one then it works fine (see attached screenshot from synaptic package manager and powershell) but now I'm just looking to automate this as I'm a lazy sloth :D 
[image]

Comment: Apparently stackexchange wont let me open with: Hi guys and gals so I'll just do it here then:
Hi guys and gals :D

Comment: you should look to expect and send command : https://askubuntu.com/questions/307067/how-to-execute-sudo-commands-with-expect-send-commands-in-bash-script

Answer (score 2):

The solution breaks down into two parts.

### First Part - Running the script

The process is simple. You have to pass the whole script as an argument to bash.

```
bash -c 'export DISPLAY=:0 ; sudo <app_name>'
```

> I do not use powershell. So escape relevant parts according to powershell syntax in the above line.

### Second Part - Skiping the password

To do this you need to allow passwordless login in the `sudoers` file located at `/etc/sudoers`. Type the following snippet (replace `user` with your `username`) at the end of `/etc/sudoers` using `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`.

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This however will change the default behaviour of sudo and the said user wont be ever requested for password when using `sudo`